# require Angularfire via browserify

Tags: javascript, angularjs, browserify, angularfire, npm-install

I have installed Angularfire via NPM, but when I try to use it inside my Angular app, it says

> firebase.initializeApp is not a function

This is how I'm trying to use it right now

```
var angular = require('angular');
var firebase = require('angularfire/index.js');

firebase.initializeApp({
    apiKey: "key",
    authDomain: "app.firebase.com",
    databaseURL: "app.firebase.com",
    storageBucket: "app.appspot.com",
});

var structurator = angular.module('structurator', ['firebase']);
```

That index.js is because I noticed that Angularfire exports itself using this code inside index.js

```
// Make sure dependencies are loaded on the window
require('angular');
require('firebase');

// Load the Angular module which uses window.angular and window.Firebase
require('./dist/angularfire');

// Export the module name from the Angular module
module.exports = 'firebase';
```

I've also tried importing just Angularfire without Firebase, importing both Angularfire and Firebase and referencing both... etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, since index.js is specified as the main file under angularfire/package.json, you can just `require('angularfire')`.

You also need to assign your imports to variables:

```
var firebase = require('firebase');
var angular = require('angular');
var angularfire = require('angularfire');
```

Then the rest of your code should work:

```
var firebase = require('firebase');
var angular = require('angular');
var angularfire = require('angularfire');

firebase.initializeApp({
    apiKey: "key",
    authDomain: "app.firebase.com",
    databaseURL: "app.firebase.com",
    storageBucket: "app.appspot.com",
});

var structurator = angular.module('structurator', ['firebase']);
```